# VisualStudio's QuickReplace finds it with RegEx but won't replace it

Tags: regex, visual-studio, replace

I'm trying to replace parts within my code that looks like this

```
Class.Method<>("SomeKeyHere"]
```

Notice the square bracket at the ending - that's what I want to replace with the correct bracket.

My RegEx to find it looks like this:

```
Class\.Method\<\>\("{[^"]+}"\]
```

This RegEx seems to find the occurences pretty well.
My RegEx I want to use to replace (with the correct bracket at the end) is this:

```
Class\.Method\<\>\("(\1)"\)
```

However, VS is finding everything using Quickfind or Quickreplace's Find button but it won't replace it, telling me it hasn't found any occurences

Comment: Please mention which version of Visual Studio, as the regexp syntax changed in either VS2012 or 2013.

Comment: The Version is VS2010 Professional

Comment: The reason that may have been important is that the syntax for capturing expressions changed, and also `$1` is used in the replace text rather than `\1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was, that Visual Studio seems not to understand, that the "Replace with"-Part contained RegEx.

The Regex that worked was:

```
Class.Method<>(\"\1\")
```

Simpler, than I thought. Seems like VisualStudio only understands the \1, \2,.. Parts within the "Replace with" field.